# Dynamically creating objects from class in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've looked around but have not found a topic answering my problem. If you know of one feel free to redirect me to it.

I have two dictionaries created dynamically. [EDIT : by 'dynamically' I mean that the size of these dictionaries will vary depending on the file i fed to the program. As indicated in one of the comments, I may be misusing this word. Please forgive.]

One contains strings of R,G,B values and looks like this :

```
colors = {0: ('255', '255', '255'), 1: ('255', '148', '0'), 2: ('238', '245', '0'), 3: ('255', '0', '0')}
```

The other contains index informations for those R,G,B values and looks like this :

```
index = {511: 0, 365: 1, 488: 2, 500:0, ...}
```

I've created a class :

```
class ColorArray:
    indexArray = []
    color = ""
```

I would now like to create as many objects from that class as I have of values in my 'colors' dict, then append into the indexArray attribute of these objects all the matching keys from the 'index' dictionary

It would look something like this :

```
>>>print(ColorArray0.color)
('255', '255', '255')
>>>print(ColorArray1.color)
('255', '148', '0')
>>>ColorArray0.indexArray.append(511)
>>>ColorArray1.indexArray.append(365)
```

Comment: There are many issues with your code. First off, the `indexArray` attribute is shared through all instances of `ColorArray`, meaning an `append` in an instance will affect all other instances of `ColorArray`. Second, you probably don't want to create hundreds of variables. Rather create a `dict` where a key is <what you want> and value is a `ColorArray` object instance. Also, it's very unclear what you're trying to do in the end. It's a ["XY problem"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamically"? I don't believe you're using it in any standard way.

Comment: I understand that what i'm trying to do is unclear and that this seems like an "XY problem". As the level of my question indicates, i'm quite new to python. In the above example, the 'index' dictionary is shown with only 4 pair of values but in fact it has hundreds. I need to split that back down into lists containing the keys of that dict and using the values to sort them. The answer from @Netwave seems to be doing just that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just define how to handle that in your class `__init__`, yes you should create instances of the class not create class attributes:

```
class ColorArray(object):
    def __init__(self, id, color, index = None):
        self.id = id
        self.colors = color
        self.index_array = [x for x, y in index.items() if y == id] if index else []
```

Then just collect the class to your dict items:

```
result = [ColorArray(id, color, index) for id, color in colors.items()]
```

Here you have a [live example](https://repl.it/repls/TriangularBoilingHertz)